# Redis GetObjectByID

Tags: c#, mongodb, casting, redis, bson

I'm trying to get an object using the following function, and while this is working fine for objects of type Medicine and MedicineBlock, I'm having trouble with MedicineStorage, the part where the data is supposed to be Set in Redis, here is the code of the function.

```
public RedisMedicine()
    {
        cache = new RedisClient(RedisConfig.SingleHost);
    }

public MedicineStorage GetMedStorageById(ObjectId id)
    {
        prepareConnection();
        cache.As<MedicineStorage>();
        MedicineStorage meds = cache.Get<MedicineStorage>("MedicineStorage" + id.ToString());
        if (meds != null)
        {
            cache.Set<MedicineStorage>("MedicineStorage" + meds.storageName, meds, new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0));
            return meds;
        }
        else
        {
            MongoCollection medsCollection = db.GetCollection<MedicineStorage>("storage");
            meds = medsCollection.FindOneByIdAs<MedicineStorage>(id);
            cache.Set<MedicineStorage>("MedicineStorage" + meds.storageName, meds, new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0));
            return meds;
        }
    }
```

The error I'm getting is System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonObjectId' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonBoolean'.'

Here is the sample of other similar function that is working without any problems.

```
public MedicineBlock GetMedBlockById(ObjectId id)
    {
        prepareConnection();
        cache.As<MedicineBlock>();
        MedicineBlock meds = cache.Get<MedicineBlock>("MedicineBlock" + id.ToString());
        if (meds != null)
        {
            cache.Set<MedicineBlock>("MedicineBlock" + meds.id, meds, new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0));
            return meds;
        }
        else
        {
            MongoCollection medsCollection = db.GetCollection<Medicine>("blok");
            meds = medsCollection.FindOneByIdAs<MedicineBlock>(id);
            cache.Set<MedicineBlock>("MedicineBlock" + meds.id, meds, new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0));
            return meds;
        }
    }
```

Running in Debug mode I can see that the object is actually present and has all the correct values but for some reason it cannot be Set to Redis. Any idea for the solution?

Comment: `The error I'm getting` On what line?

Comment: As I said, the line where the data is supposed to be Set in Redis, that is:
cache.Set<MedicineStorage>("MedicineStorage" + meds.storageName, meds, new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0));

Comment: The first one of them, or the second?

Comment: They are the same, but I'm getting on the second one since there are no objects in Database, hence the code will never reach the first one, as seen by IF statement.